# Super script text inside QStandardItem

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, superscript

I currently have text inside a `QStandardItem` which is "mm3" , now this is suppose to be millimeter cuber. Is there any way for me to make it mm^3 (i.e superscript 3) in the view ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sup` HTML tag to have a super script. So `mm<sup>3</sup>` in a widget that supports rich text, results in a super script.

Here you should have a custom delegate to show rich text for a specific column. Just create a custom `QStyledItemDelegate`. It could be like :

```
class RichTextDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    RichTextDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    void paint( QPainter *painter,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;
};

RichTextDelegate::RichTextDelegate(QObject *parent):QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void RichTextDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    if( option.state & QStyle::State_Selected )
        painter->fillRect( option.rect, option.palette.highlight() );


    painter->save();

    QTextDocument document;
    document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width());
    QVariant value = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole);
    if (value.isValid() && !value.isNull())
    {
                document.setHtml(value.toString());
                painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
                document.drawContents(painter);

    }

    painter->restore();
}
```

You should set the item delegate for the specific column :

```
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(colIndex, new RichTextDelegate(ui->tableView));
```

Now if you set the model text for the specific column in a row to `mm<sup>3</sup>`, it will be shown properly :

```
model->item(rowIndex,  colIndex)->setText(mm<sup>3</sup>);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of showing a superscript '3', another option would be to use the corresponding Unicode symbol - Qt's text rendering should find a suitable glyph in either your main font or a fallback one. However, this is much less general-purpose than the answer above - it only works for various commonly defined superscripts.